# "com.microsoft.graph.core.ClientException: Error during http request" while trying to delete message with Microsoft Graph API

Tags: java, android, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

I've created an Android app (Java) that uses Microsoft Graph Mail API to read and delete messages (emails). Reading messages works, but deleting results in this error

```
com.microsoft.graph.core.ClientException: Error during http request
```

Reading messages **(runs successfully)**:

```
    final String accessToken = authenticationResult.getAccessToken();

    IGraphServiceClient graphClient =
            GraphServiceClient
                    .builder()
                    .authenticationProvider(new IAuthenticationProvider() {
                        @Override
                        public void authenticateRequest(IHttpRequest request) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Authenticating request," + request.getRequestUrl());
                            request.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
                        }
                    })
                    .buildClient();

             graphClient
                    .me()
                    .messages()
                    .buildRequest()
                    .select("id, subject, body, from")
                    .top(50)
                    .get(new ICallback<IMessageCollectionPage>() {
                        @Override
                        public void success(IMessageCollectionPage iMessageCollectionPage) {
                            displayGraphResult(iMessageCollectionPage.getRawObject());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void failure(ClientException ex) {
                            displayError(ex);
                        }
                    });
```

Here's the API call to delete a message:

```
                 graphClient
                        .me()
                        .messages(graph_id)
                        .buildRequest()
                        .delete(new ICallback<Message>() {
                            @Override
                            public void success(Message message) {
                                Log.d("DeleteAPI", "Successfully deleted!");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void failure(ClientException ex) {
                                Log.d("DeleteAPIError", ex.toString());
                                displayError(ex);
                            }
                        });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yikes. When I extracted the graph_id from the get request it was surrounded by quotations. I removed the quotations and now the delete call is working properly